# The reducer of MapReduce program is not giving desired output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to construct the first phase(Frequency calculation) of an algorithm Attribute Value Frequency using MapReduce where the frequency of each attribute across each column is calculated. I am mentioning the desired key-value pairs in my problem.So hope it wont be problematic even if the algorithm is not familiar to you.I have a dataset as follows:

```
ID1,2,1,4
ID2,2,2,2
ID3,5,3,1
```

Each row has a ID followed by the value of three attributes. In the map phase,I need to generate [attributeNo attributeValue] as key and [ID] as value. I have designed and executed the map phase correctly. I tested my map phase by directly printing its generated key-value pairs in the reduce phase without any processing. And i found that the key-value pairs have been generated correctly ie, the reduce phase is getting correct input from the map phase. My map class is :

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> 
{              
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
    {
       String[] rows = value.toString().split("\r?\n");          
       for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
           String[] cols = rows[i].toString().split(",");
           String v=cols[0];
           for(int j=1;j<cols.length;j++)
           {
               String k =j+","+cols[j];
               output.collect(new Text(k),new Text(v));
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Correct key-value pairs generated in map phase:

```
2,3  ID3
3,2  ID2
1,5  ID3
1,2  ID1,ID2
2,1  ID1
3,4  ID1
2,2  ID2
3,1  ID3
```

Now these key value pairs of map are fed as input to the reduce. My reduce phase need to generate [ID,attributeNo] as key and [attributeValue,frequency] as value where frequency is the number of IDs corresponding to each key. My reduce class is:

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text>output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
        {

            /** map phase check
            while (values.hasNext()) 
            {
               String s = (values.next()).toString();
               output.collect(key,new Text(s));            


            }**/

            // Frequency Calculation
            int count =0;                
            String[] attr = key.toString().split(",");      
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

           while(values.hasNext())               
            {
                list.add((values.next()).toString());
                count++;

            }

            String v=attr[1]+","+count;
           for(String s:list)
           { 
               String k=s+","+attr[0];
               output.collect(new Text(k),new Text(v));
           }

        }
```

I am getting an output :

```
2,1,ID3  3,1
3,1,ID3  2,1
5,1,ID3  1,1
2,2,ID1  1,1
2,2,ID2  1,1
1,1,ID1  2,1
4,1,ID1  3,1
2,1,ID1  2,1
1,1,ID3  3,1
```

The desired output is:

```
ID1,1  2,2
ID1,2  1,1
ID1,3  4,1
ID2,1  2,1
ID2,2  2,1
ID2,3  2,1
ID3,1  4,1
ID3,2  2,1
ID3,3  1,1
```

Please can you tell me what is wrong with my code or logic in the reduce phase ? Even the format of keys generated in the reduce phase is not right. Please help me correct the output to the reduce phase.

Comment: Shouldn't `ID2,1` be `2,2` since the value `2` occurs for ID1 and ID2?

Comment: yes yes u r absolutely correct ..i made a mistake while calculating the output...it will be ID2,1  2,2...Plz can you suggest me the pairs of key-value that needs to generated at both map and reduce phase

Comment: Sorry, but from your code above, I don't see how you are getting the key values out of the reducer you are. Seems like the Mapper is correct for what you need.